# Spark data sets to parquet file conversion

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I am new to spark/scala programming. I'm trying to save spark datasets to parquet file but only parquet directory is getting created without any sub-directory or files inside it.

code snipet:
object Dimension1 {
  case class DIM_DATE_PR(
    date_key:              Int,
    date_fld:              Timestamp,
    date_name:             String,
    date_key_ly:           Int,
    date_fld_ly:           Timestamp,
    day_in_year:           Int,
    day_in_month:          Int,
    day_in_week:           Int,
    day_type:              String,
    year_of_day:           Int,
    year_name:             Int,
    half_in_year:          Int,
    half_year_name:        String,
    quarter_in_year:       Int,
    quarter_name:          String,
    month_in_quarter:      Int,
    month_in_year:         Int,
    month_name:            String,
    week_in_year:          String,
    week_name_in_year:     String,
    week_in_month:         String,
    week_name_in_month:    String,
    week_st_date_key:      String,
    week_end_date_key:     Int,
    month_st_date_key:     Int,
    month_end_date_key:    Int,
    week_number_this_year: Int,
    year:                  Int,
    quarter:               Int,
    ca_date_key:           Int,
    day_type_seq:          Int,
    year_st_date_key:      Int,
    date_key_ly_day2day:   Int,
    date_key_ct_ly:        Int)

def mapper(line: String): DIM_DATE_PR = {

```
val fields = line.split("\\|", -1)
val formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
val DIM_DATE_PRL1: DIM_DATE_PR = DIM_DATE_PR(
  fields(0).toInt,
  new Timestamp(formatter.parse(fields(1)).getTime),
  fields(2),
  if (fields(3).isEmpty()) { 0 } else { fields(3).toInt },
  if (fields(4).isEmpty()) { new Timestamp(formatter.parse("2012-04-01 00:00:00").getTime) } else { new Timestamp(formatter.parse(fields(4)).getTime) },
  fields(5).toInt,
  fields(6).toInt,
  fields(7).toInt,
  fields(8),
  fields(9).toInt,
  fields(10).toInt,
  fields(11).toInt,
  fields(12),
  fields(13).toInt,
  fields(14),
  fields(15).toInt,
  fields(15).toInt,
  fields(16),
  fields(17),
  fields(18),
  fields(19),
  fields(20),
  fields(21),
  fields(22).toInt,
  fields(23).toInt,
  fields(25).toInt,
  if (fields(26).isEmpty()) { 0 } else { fields(26).toInt },
  if (fields(27).isEmpty()) { 0 } else { fields(27).toInt },
  if (fields(28).isEmpty()) { 0 } else { fields(28).toInt },
  if (fields(29).isEmpty()) { 0 } else { fields(29).toInt },
  if (fields(30).isEmpty()) { 0 } else { fields(30).toInt },
  fields(31).toInt,
  if (fields(32).isEmpty()) { 0 } else { fields(32).toInt },
  if (fields(33).isEmpty()) { 0 } else { fields(33).toInt })
return DIM_DATE_PRL1
```

}

/** Our main function where the action happens */
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

```
// Set the log level to only print errors
Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

// Use new SparkSession interface in Spark 2.0
val spark = SparkSession
  .builder
  .appName("SparkSQL")
  .master("local[*]")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/temp") // Necessary to work around a Windows bug in Spark 2.0.0; omit if you're not on Windows.
  .getOrCreate()

// Convert our csv file to a DataSet, using our Person case
// class to infer the schema.
import spark.implicits._
//val dataPath_tim = "D:\Project_Scala_Code_Optimizor\Input.txt" //args(0)
// val lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("D:/Project_Scala_Code_Optimizor/input.txt")
val datardd_tim = spark.sparkContext.textFile("D:/Project_Scala_Code_Optimizor/Input.txt")
val timedimds = datardd_tim.map(mapper).toDS().cache()
 timedimds.write.parquet("D:/Project_Scala_Code_Optimizor/dimension.parquet")
spark.stop()
```

}
}

Comment: Your attached error log is a broken link. Please [edit] your question and paste the error as text.

Comment: 2018-06-05 16:05:34 ERROR Utils:91 - Aborting task
java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 D:\Project_Scala_Code_Optimizor\dimension.parquet\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20180605160534_0002_m_000000_0\part-00000-7d125dcc-5aa1-4d6b-8663-ff0e93c2850c-c000.snappy.parquet
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)

Comment: 2018-06-05 16:05:34 ERROR FileFormatWriter:70 - Job job_20180605160534_0002 aborted.
2018-06-05 16:05:34 ERROR FileFormatWriter:70 - Job job_20180605160534_0002 aborted.
2018-06-05 16:05:34 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 D:\Project_Scala_Code_Optimizor\dimension.parquet\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20180605160534_0002_m_000000_0\part-00000-7d125dcc-5aa1-4d6b-8663-ff0e93c2850c-c000.snappy.parquet
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)

Comment: 2018-06-05 16:05:34 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 1.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 3)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 D:\Project_Scala_Code_Optimizor\dimension.parquet\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20180605160534_0002_m_000001_0\part-00001-7d125dcc-5aa1-4d6b-8663-ff0e93c2850c-c000.snappy.parquet
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)

Comment: 2018-06-05 16:05:34 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
2018-06-05 16:05:34 ERROR FileFormatWriter:91 - Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 D:\Project_Scala_Code_Optimizor\dimension.parquet\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20180605160534_0002_m_000000_0\part-00000-7d125dcc-5aa1-4d6b-8663-ff0e93c2850c-c000.snappy.parquet
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)

Comment: ... 22 more
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$FileFormatWriter$$executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:285)
 at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$$anonfun$write$1.apply(FileFormatWriter.scala:197)

Comment: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: (null) entry in command string: null chmod 0644 D:\Project_Scala_Code_Optimizor\dimension.parquet\_temporary\0\_temporary\attempt_20180605160534_0002_m_000000_0\part-00000-7d125dcc-5aa1-4d6b-8663-ff0e93c2850c-c000.snappy.parquet
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:770)
 at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:866)

Comment: Please refer the commented log information for more details...Since i am not able to attach the log/text file hence i am trying to put some errors in comment sections. Your help is appreciated.